# Using dates in oracle prepared statements from .net4

Tags: .net, oracle

Given this table:

```
myTable
EMPID           NOT NULL CHAR(10)      
DEFFECTIVE      NOT NULL DATE 
SSCHEME                  CHAR(10)
```

and this prepared statement:

```
update myTable set sScheme = :sScheme  
where empID = :sEmpID                 
and dEffective= :dStart
```

with these parameters:

```
OCmd.Parameters.Add("sEmpID", OracleDbType.Char).Value = sEmp_No        'string
OCmd.Parameters.Add("dStart", OracleDbType.Date).Value = dtStart        'System.DateTime
OCmd.Parameters.Add("sScheme", OracleDbType.Char).Value = sScheme       'string
```

Why do I keep getting Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

I see lots of people suggesting to pass the date in as formatted string and then do a to_date in the query - but that just seems a horribly backward step.

Have tried using SetSessionInfo (from OracleGlobalization) to match the DateFormat as specified by Culture but to no avail.

Initially this app was running a .net2 using the MS oracle provider with no issues, but moving to .net4 and Oracle.DataAccess causes me this headache.

Using System.DateTime as the .net type for the date as per instructions here: http://docs.oracle.com/html/E15167_01/featTypes.htm

.net framework 4
Oracle.DataAccess (v4.112.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

I'd forgotten about Oracle.DataAccess defaulting to BindByName = false.

Solution:  OCmd.BindByName = True

Comment: So actually the problem wasn't about the date format - it was that Oracle was binding the parameters as per the order they were being applied. Changed to BindByName=True and everything worked just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that, in the background, the date is passed as a string. And you need to have the good format so that Oracle can reconvert the date to its intended format.

Two solutions:
the first one is to use the to_date...
the second is to change the date format of the client. For this, you have two ways:
  - at the OS level:
    export NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' (export for linux, set for windows)
  - in the software:
    sql 'alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

In both cases, you have to find the 'good' format.

You can also change the format by changing the country code of the client. usually, the Oracle side is intended to your with US formats. So an 
export LANG=C (or en_US.UTF-8)
Will do the trick.

But, as much Oracle is clear on how it works, I found that others are not always. so you have to experiment...

First thing, print a date to know which default format is used...

Or just use to_date... Which, even if it is ugly, will always do the job...

regards